# Quadratic hypothesis in linear regression always goes wrong

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am a beginner and the code is purely experimental and might be inconvenient so sorry about that (eg: I am using a large number in for loop for continous loop)

Hypothesis is in form :- ax^2+bx+c and parameters are a, b and c.

Testing Data and Output

```
x=[10,20,30,40,50]
y=[-50,-90,-130,-170,-210]
```

Hypothesis function

```
def h(m):
    return a*(x[m]**2)+b*x[m]+c
```

Changing parameters

```
for i in range(1,300000000):
    for j in range (0,4):
        c1=c1+(h(j)-y[j])
        b1=b1+(h(j)-y[j])*(x[j])
        a1=a1+(h(j)-y[j])*(x[j])**2

a=a-0.00000046*0.20*a1
b=b-0.00000046*0.20*b1
c=c-0.00000046*0.20*c1
```

Cost function

```
for k in range(0, 4):
    s = s + (h(k) - y[k])**2
cost=1/5*s
```

The answer should be a=0, b=-4 and c=-10 but i get a=0.02 (which increases after every loop), b=-5.4946 and c=11 when cost is around 2 (I didn't actually end the code execution so sorry for inconvenience)

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got pretty much everything right, there are only two issues. See inline comments:

```
# reliance on global/upper scope variables is a bad practice
def h(a, b, c, value):
    return a*(value**2)+b*value+c

# don't repeat yourself - define it in one place rather than 3
lr = 0.00000046*0.20  # learning rate
for i in range(1,300000000):

    # first issue: a1, b1 and c1 need to be reset
    a1 = b1 = c1 = 0

    # hardcoding magic constants (including data shape) is a bad practice
    for x_, y_ in range zip(x, y):
        diff = h(a, b, c, x_)-y_
        c1 += diff
        b1 += diff * x[j]
        a1 += diff * x[j]**2

    # second issue: this needs to be done every "batch"
    a -= lr * a1
    b -= lr * b1
    c -= lr * c1
```

This would be a lot more efficient in vector form, but I hope you get the idea